# GreetingCard problem with Coordinates

Tags: java, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

This is a practice problem on [Kattis](https://open.kattis.com/problems/greetingcard)

I have exceeded the time limit for the 5th out of 11 test case. Can anyone inspire me what could be done to optimize the code?

**Problem Description**

> Quido plans to send a New Year greeting to his friend Hugo. He has
>   recently acquired access to an advanced high-precision plotter and he
>   is planning to print the greeting card on the plotter.
>
> Here’s how the plotter operates. In step one, the plotter plots an
>   intricate pattern of **n** dots on the paper. In step two, the picture
>   in the greeting emerges when the plotter connects by a straight
>   segment each pair of dots that are exactly **2018** length units
>   apart.
>
> The plotter uses a special holographic ink, which has a limited
>   supply. Quido wants to know the number of all plotted segments in the
>   picture to be sure that there is enough ink to complete the job.
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line of input contains a positive integer n specifying the
>   number of plotted points. The following n lines each contain a pair of
>   space-separated integer coordinates indicating one plotted point. Each
>   coordinate is non-negative and less than **2^31**. There are at most
>   **10^5** points, all of them are distinct.
>
> In this problem, all coordinates and distances are expressed in
>   plotter length units, the length of the unit in the x-direction and in
>   the y-direction is the same.
>
> **Output**
>
> The output contains a single integer equal to the number of pairs of
>   points which are exactly **2018** length units apart.

**Sample input**

```
4
20180000 20180000
20180000 20182018
20182018 20180000
20182018 20182018
```

**Output**

```
4
```

Here is my code

```
import java.util.*;

class Coordinates {
    int x;
    int y;

    public Coordinates(int x,int y) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    public double distanceWith(Coordinates z) {
        return Math.hypot((x-z.x),(y-z.y));
    }
}

class GreetingCard {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        HashSet<Coordinates> set = new HashSet<>();
        int count = sc.nextInt();
        int total = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            int y = sc.nextInt();
            Coordinates curr = new Coordinates(x,y);
            if (i!=0) {
                total+=findDistances(curr, set);
            }
            set.add(curr);
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }

    public static int findDistances(Coordinates curr, HashSet<Coordinates> set) {
        int total = 0;
        for (Coordinates inside : set) {
            if (inside.distanceWith(curr)==2018) {
                total+=1;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Calculating the distance between each pair of points is expensive. Since the coordinates are all integers, you can first calculate which delta-x and delta-y can lead to the distance 2018 at all. Define a function `candidates(point, set)` that filters the possible candidates. To do this efficiently, group the points by their x coordinate. Then, for a given x, you only have to look at a few of these groups.

Grouping the points improves performance because grouping has complexity around \$\mathcal O(n)\$, where \$n\$ is the number of points.

Afterwards, finding the candidate points is a simple lookup: for each delta in (-2018, -1680, -1118, 0, 1118, 1860, 2018) you need one lookup, which again sums up to \$\mathcal O(n)\$.

In summary, the number of comparisons will be much less than the \$n\cdot n\$ from your current code.

Comment: Strictly speaking, how would you know if a particular arithmetic operation is expensive, after all a comparison is still made even in the filtering process that you suggested, why would it make such a big difference?

Comment: I expanded my answer a bit.